# card drawing with replacement

Tags: probability

If 6 cards are drawn from a deck of cards with replacement.  What is the probability that the outcome is a club at least once.  I thought it would be 13/52.  But I was wrong.

Comment: Hint: this would follow a binomial distribution, each card draw is a bernoulli rv with $p=\frac{1}{4}$. Also notice $P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)$

Comment: Plus go more in depth how you got your answer so we can better help you

Answer (score 2):

If you don't draw a club at least once, you draw zero.

The odds of not drawing a club on a particular draw is $\frac{3}{4}$. Since you replace the card each time, each of the draws is from a full deck, and so the events are independent. Thus, the chance of drawing a nonclub 6 times is

$$P(\text{no clubs}) = \underbrace{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}_n = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^6 = \frac{729}{4096},$$

and so the chance of drawing a least one club in $6$ draws is

$$P(\text{at least $1$ club}) = 1 - P(\text{no clubs}) = 1 - \frac{729}{4096} = \frac{3367}{4096} = 0.82202\ldots .$$